# Jplayer 2.1.0 dosen't work on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, jplayer

I cant get Jplayer 2.1.0 to work on IE9 (didn't check prev versions- I don't bother with them). This code works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Opera. It's supposed to autostart and play in a loop. I've tried everything to make this work, but since I'm not a real coder, my efforts were vain.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://www.tomziebinski.com/sounds/1.mp3"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        ended: function(){
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://www.tomziebinski.com/sounds/2.mp3"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },

        swfPath: "http://www.tomziebinski.com/jQuery.jPlayer.2.1.0",
        supplied: "mp3",
        loop: "true",
        volume: 0.3
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the correct MIME types have been added? This is usually a good place to start when files play in one browser but not another.

Have a look here at the MIME type chapter under server response: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/
and here: http://forums.contribs.org/index.php?topic=38947.0

Comment: yes, they are added correctly. I see that this is a wider problem as lots of ppl get this, I also checked the official demos on jplayer website and they also don't seem to work on IE9. Its so ironic to put so much effort in making something work on a browser thats on its way out...